# TortoiseSVN failure, cannot commit after path changes

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I tried to change up some of the directory structure (using tortoise svn) and I ran into trouble when I tried to commit (everything is fully updated):

```
Commit failed (details follow):
'/simulation-code/swsim/!svn/bc/98/src/Analysis/Julia's%20Movies/Movie' path
not found
```

I'm not sure what the problem is or how to fix it, and it won't let me commit. I did move some files around / deleted and added a folder, but I did it using TortiseSVN, so idk why it is not working.

Thanks,

Tyler

Comment: What do you mean by "I did it using TortoiseSVN"? What commands and menu entries do you have used? It could be a problem of mixing changes on the server and on the client simultaneously ...

Comment: I did a right drag slash right-click, SVN delete using TortoiseSVN via windows. I just didn't update my changes to that part of the code and tried again when I commited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the above is the only file giving error, how about reverting just that change and commiting the rest?

Refer to this discussion for a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819896/how-do-i-correct-commit-failed-file-xxx-is-out-of-date-xxx-path-not-found), which may be relevant.