# SVN 'path not found' when trying to add a new file

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I am having an issue trying to add a file to an SVN repo and can't find out what's wrong.

I created my trunk folder and all the project files using VisualSVN from within Visual studio, everything's checked in and working copies are all up to date.

On another computer, I have a file called OnBoardFlash.dat, which is an image of the flash drive for the .NET MicroFramework emulator. I want to add this file in to my repository. So I copied it into the project folder, right click, SVN Add, then right click, SVN Commit. The file gets transferred to the server, all 72Mb of it, then at the end I get this error message:

```
Commit
C:\Users\Tim Long\Desktop\Tigra.Project\Tigra.Project\OnBoardFlash.dat
C:\Users\Tim Long\Desktop\Tigra.Project\Tigra.Project\OnBoardFlash.dat
C:\Users\Tim Long\Desktop\Tigra.Project\Tigra.Project\OnBoardFlash.dat
Commit failed (details follow):
File 'C:\Users\Tim Long\Desktop\Tigra.Project\Tigra.Project\OnBoardFlash.dat'
 is out of date
'/svn/TiGra/!svn/txr/1166-yp/Tigra.Project/trunk/Tigra.Project/OnBoardFlash.dat'
 path not found
You have to update your working copy first.
```

Eh? I don't understand the error message. It goes without saying that I have tried updating the working copy and running the cleanup command - but its a fresh checkout so it should be squaky clean. There can be no question of the path not existing because there are other files in the folder (both WC and Repo). It exists. Also, what does it mean by 'out of date'? It is a newly added file. I'm sure there is a simple answer to this but for the moment, it escapes me. I am hoping you all can shed some light on it.

Just as a sanity check, I tried adding the file directly from the Repo Browser, bypassing the working copy altogether. I get a less verbose but similar error message 'path not found'. Help!

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819896/how-do-i-correct-commit-failed-file-xxx-is-out-of-date-xxx-path-not-found

Comment: In my opinion, although the error message is the same, the situation is quite different to that in 819896. This should have been a trivial operation - add a file and commit it. There's nothing funky going on with versions or repos as far as I can tell.